# Azure ML sales prediction

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a simple SQL table, with historical sales data for products. The fields are Product Identifier, Sale Date and Quantity.  Each product has multiple entries/sales.

I want to be able to generate sales forecasts for all products using Azure ML, for certain time periods.

I've found examples/tutorials(e.g. https://gallery.azure.ai/Collection/Retail-Forecasting-Template-1 ) but they are too complicated for my use case.

What would be a flow to achieve what I need? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For time-series you will find lots of good tutorials but I strongly suggest the following ones.

- [Time Series Forecasting as Supervised Learning](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-supervised-learning/)
- [How to Grid Search Deep Learning Models for Time Series Forecasting](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-grid-search-deep-learning-models-for-time-series-forecasting/)
- [How To Backtest Machine Learning Models for Time Series Forecasting](https://machinelearningmastery.com/backtest-machine-learning-models-time-series-forecasting/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I need something mapped on the Azure environment.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it helped me understand a little better the overall picture.